# Unable to change the background color, for bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the background color to black. But its not working.
Is it a problem with the .css reference links which i provided? background images are working perfectly, but when i want to just make a plain background with a specific color, it is always showing white.

I've even tried adding !important, "background-color: black !important;... but still no use.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Project Selector</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/1.1.0/annyang.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>


    body {
      position: relative;
    }

    #home {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 667px;
      background-color: black;
    }

    h1.h11 {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      top: 250px;
    }

  </style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="projectf.html">Projects</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapses">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
          <li><a href="#LoT">List of topics</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tutorial">Tutorial</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="home">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="h11">Project Selection Interface</h1>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- JQUERY JS file -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using an ID in your CSS and not a class as you are in the html

Offending code

```
#home{
padding-top:50px;
height:667px;
background-color:black;

}
```

Corrected Code

```
.home{
padding-top:50px;
height:667px;
background-color:black;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the color of `id="home"` (`#home`), where you don't have any `id="home"`, and you should change the `#` to `.` in order to affect `class="home"`.

This could work:

```
.home{
     padding-top:50px;
     height:667px;
     background-color:black;
}
```

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32cfx7m4/)

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
.home {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 667px;
  background-color: black;
}
h1.h11 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="projectf.html">Projects</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapses">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#search">Search</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#LoT">List of topics</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#tutorial">Tutorial</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="home">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="h11">Project Selection Interface</h1>

  </div>
</div>
```